# Sync Carto dataset using Import API

Tags: carto

I have imported a dataset from a url http://api.gdeltproject.org/api/v1/gkg_geojson?QUERY=TERROR%22&TIMESPAN=1440&OUTPUTFIELDS=url,name,sharingimage and I want to sync it now using API.

I followed the instructions here https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/import-api/sync-tables and typed in

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"http://api.gdeltproject.org/api/v1/gkg_geojson?QUERY=TERROR%22&TIMESPAN=1440&OUTPUTFIELDS=url,name,sharingimage":"https://public.url.to.file/sample_file", "interval":"3600"}' "https://sengyapglobalmomentum.carto.com/api/v1/synchronizations/?api_key=API_KEY"
```

However, this error shows up

Did I carried out any wrong steps?

Comment: Please include any errors as text rather than pictures.  That way they are available to future searches by anyone having the same problem.  Don't forget to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 2):

The Curl operation is not done in CARTO. You would need to open the computer Terminal and write the Curl command.

Curl is a a command line tool for doing all sorts of URL manipulations and transfers. [Here](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html) you can find a tutorial for using Curl.

On the other hand, I would strongly recommend you to change your API KEY as soon as possible. Anyone with access to your api key can download or modify your data without your permission.

Comment: I have changed the API key. Thank you. So my curl operation is correct, except that it should be keyed into the computer Terminal, not SQL table?

Comment: exactly :) If you are using windows, you would need to install Curl. Explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507353/how-do-i-install-set-up-and-use-curl-on-a-windows

Comment: If I am installing Curl, do I still need to use the computer Terminal / Command Prompt?

Comment: yes, you need to use it

Comment: I typed in the long curl command in command prompt, but it returns with a message that says curl: no URl specified. Do you know what it means?